# Template class with different order or variables (Color/Pixel class)

Tags: c++, templates

I got two class templates Color3_t and Color4_t that store 3 and 4 color channels and look like this:

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct Color3_t
{
   TYPE Red;
   TYPE Green;
   TYPE Blue;

   void Zero()
   {
      Red = Green = Blue = 0;
   }
   (...)
}
```

Both templates have several function for inverting, swapping etc. color channels and I got another specialized templates that inherit these classes - in case the TYPE is a half float or float instead of integer.

The problem is that the order of color channels : Red,Green and Blue is currently fixed - which means that I would have to create a version of Color3_t class template for each other order of color channels (like BGR, GRB etc.). How can provide and argument with different color order - most likely that points to a color structure like below.

Color data structures for RGB and BGR color order:

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct ColorRGB_t
{
   TYPE Red;
   TYPE Green;
   TYPE Blue;
};

template <typename TYPE>
struct ColorBGR_t
{
   TYPE Blue;
   TYPE Green;
   TYPE Red;
};
```

and something I'd like to have - which is obviously wrong and incorrect but should give an idea what I want to achieve.

```
template <typename TYPE, class COLORORDER<TYPE>>
struct Color3_t : public COLORORDER<TYPE>
{
   void Zero()
   {
      Red = Green = Blue = 0;
   }
   (...)   
};
```

I also would like to access each color channel directly:

```
typedef Color3_t<BYTE,ColorBGR_t<BYTE>> ColorRGB8bpc;
ColorRGB8bpc oColor;
oColor.Red = 0;
```

instead of:

```
oColor.SomoObject.Red = 0;
```

Comment: When would the order of the members matter?

Comment: Also. Why would the order matter?

Comment: For accessing these object (structures) in arrays or memory buffers - after you load the raw data from a file - to access them by names not direct indices 0,1,2. I also got the image class that operate on different color/pixel format and using channel names instead of numbers is simply much easier.

Different file format use different order, for example BMP images use RGB, TGA use BGR no to mention that is make easier to extract 4 channel color values from ULONG/DWORDs.

Comment: I'd be surprised if accessing raw memory as `Color3_t` wouldn't yield undefined behavior. That said, when you verified that it does what you want on your platform, you might want to take Dima's idea, but have his `getX()` functions call into a traits class, passing the array. Then the traits class can determine the order of the colors.

Comment: It works fine and it's platform independent - instead of obvious DWORD issue that need to be different for little/big endian convention. I skipped the #pragma pack(1), btw.

Comment: Wouldn't it still be simpler to convert data, whatever form it comes in, to one and the same internal type? I don't see why, if the file uses RGB or BGR, your internal representation should use the same order.

Comment: This is exactly what I need it for - converting the raw data to one of the 'internal' storage types. One of a few types, because such type can be the structure of bytes (BMP,JPG,TGA),half-floats/words(EXR) or floats(TIFF). There would be no sense in storing 8bit data as floats because it would be the waste or CPU and RAM. Example: Color3<ColorRGB_t<BYTE>>* ptrSource = ...; Color3<ColorBGRA_t<BYTE> >* ptrTarget = ...; ptrTarget->Red = ptrSource->Red ... and so on; Simple, easy in use for reading the raw data from and writing to a file on both x86 and x64 platforms.

Comment: ...and if the question is: could it be done using local data structures/types in IO functions? The answer is: It could; though, it wouldn't be so beautiful;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to push the type that is stored for red/green/blue down into the Color***_t classes like so:

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct ColorRGB_t
{
   typedef TYPE value_type;

   value_type Red;
   value_type Green;
   value_type Blue;
};

template <typename TYPE>
struct ColorBGR_t
{
   typedef TYPE value_type;

   value_type Blue;
   value_type Green;
   value_type Red;
};
```

Then Color3 just take one template parameter that is one of your Color***_t types:

```
template <typename Order_t>
struct Color3 : public Order_t
{
   typedef typename Order_t::value_type value_type;

   void Zero()
   {
      //static cast zero here to avoid compiler warnings when value_type is a float or double
      Order_t::Red = Order_t::Green = Order_t::Blue = static_cast<value_type>(0);
   }
};
```

And you declare objects as:

```
Color3<ColorBGR_t<float> > c1;
Color3<ColorRGB_t<float> > c2;
```

Does that work for you? It avoids the overhead of indexing into an array at runtime and the Red/Green/Blue members are available directly like `c1.Red = 0.0`.

Comment: Seems like this is what I had in mind but couldn't find the correct syntax to express it;) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this got me thinking.

My code is based on the idea that base non-virtual classes are laid out in memory in the order they are declared. I don't think this is guaranteed, but IMO it's at least quite common. It also allows you to use your color type for different numbers of colors.

```
template <typename TYPE> struct R { TYPE Red; };
template <typename TYPE> struct G { TYPE Green; };
template <typename TYPE> struct B { TYPE Blue; };

template <typename Bases>
struct Color : inherit_from<Bases>
{
   // ...
};

typedef Color< generate_color_list<R,G,B>::result_t > ColorRGB_t;
typedef Color< generate_color_list<B,G,R>::result_t > ColorBGR_t;
```

Now all you need is `generate_color_list` and that `inherit_from`.

Given this simple type list definition

```
struct nil {};

template< typename Head, typename Tail >
struct type_list {
  typedef Head head_type;
  typedef Tail tail_type;
};
```

here's a not very generalized attempt at a color type list generator:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 >
struct generate_color_list {
  typedef type_list< T1, 
          type_list< T2, 
          type_list< T3, nil > > > result_t;
};
```

And this is a shot at the `inherit_from`:

```
template< typename List >
struct inherit_from;

template<>
struct inherit_from<nil> {}

template< typename Head, class Tail >
struct inherit_from< type_list<Head,Tail> >
  : public Head
  , public inherit_from<Tail>
{};
```

I have not tried to compile any of this, so it will have embarrassing errors. I'm blushing already.

Comment: I think the Brett's solution above is a bit simpler. Thank you.

Comment: It _is_ complicated if you don't have the `type_list` and `inherit_from` in your toolbox anyway. I have them, so all I would need are the few lines in the first code snippet. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you cannot do what you want at compile time with templates.  You probably have 
do this at run time.

To get the effect you want you would need to do something like this:

```
template < typename TYPE >
struct color3channel
{
  TYPE channels[3];

  int rIndex, bIndex, gIndex;

  TYPE getR() const {return channels[rIndex];}
  TYPE getG() const {return channels[gIndex];}
  TYPE getB() const {return channels[bIndex];}
};
```

Comment: "I am guessing you cannot do what you want at compile time with templates." One could take your idea and put those functions into a traits class. But the question remains: Why would the order matter?

Comment: Thanks but this is what I already had. As for compile time, I'd like the templates to be easier to maintain - means shorter but not for the cost of much complex code that use these templates.

Comment: The reason for different order is explained above;)